# ReactJS exporting to csv library issue

Tags: reactjs

How can i fix this issue?

[snowpack] Failed to load node_modules/react-csv/src/components/Link.js
Unexpected token (110:6) in /home/clarkeustaquio/Documents/adec/adec/client/node_modules/react-csv/src/components/Link.js
[snowpack] Dependency Install Error: Install failed.

[image]

Im using this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that is something that some folks have been experienced in https://github.com/react-csv/react-csv/issues/268
So you might try what they did to make it work.

Comment: I think the best possible way that i can do is to copy all the codes that is in the library and change the file extension to .jsx.